# C++ seekg usage?

Tags: seek

When using seekg, what parameter does seekg take. I read that it takes the position, but in the code below, using 1 or 2 for the seekg parameter gives the same result.

```
ifstream input ("numbers.in");
input.seekg(1);
int a;
input >> a;
cout << a;
```

Textfile is:
9
8
7
6

Whether I use 1 or 2 for seekg() I get 8. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=ifstream+seekg

Comment: No, I know the syntax, but why does using 1 or 2 as the seekg() parameter give the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to fix?

1 points to

```
9 8 7 6
 ^
```

and 2 points to

```
9 8 7 6
  ^
```

so both will read `8` as next `int`.